# Debugging view controller transitions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, debugging, uiviewcontroller

Is there a symbolic breakpoint or something that will trap the following warnings, so that the erroneous code can be more easily found?

> Attempt to present <> on <> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress.
>
> Trying to dismiss the presentation controller while transitioning already. (<>)

I don't have a specific problem to solve, just looking for an answer to this question, which could just be "no".

When these errors occur, how do you find out the present/dismiss call causing the problem and/or the present/dismiss that is in progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I've found so far is to run with Allocations instrumentation and "Record reference counts".
Then you can find the specific instances referenced in the logs by their address.
This will have recorded the stack traces when that object was created, presented, etc, as they all involve changes in reference count.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little more context would help us answer your question ?

- Are you using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` ?
- When are you having this issue happening ?

If you want to debug, you can use `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method for your convenience :

`- navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` or

`navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:`

If you're not already using it for your animation.

Comment: It's a general problem of trying to find out which controllers are involved in the error, not a specific issue. I'll see if breakpoints on those calls help next time.

Comment: well, i'm pretty sure you'll will be happy with the ```UINavigationControllerDelegate``` protocol ! if you need more help with your animation just come back here with more information.

Comment: Oh, in most cases they're not `UINavigationController`s. Just general `UIViewControllers`.

Comment: Well yes, the protocol is intended to use pair to pair with a navigationController. That why i wanted to get more context from you.